# Reading a csv file in d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to read a csv file into d3.js. The previous question that I am directed to does not answer correctly. When I try that code it also does not return anything in the console My code is

```
d3.xml("continents.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    d3.select("#viz").node().appendChild(importedNode);

var data = d3.csv("new_data.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    country: d.Country_Names,
    value: +d.Total // convert "Length" column to number
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});

console.log(data)
});
```

By this I wish to see the data in console however nothing appears there.

Data

```
Continent   Country_Names   Total
Europe  Albania 3.8
Europe  Armenia 5.4
Europe  Austria 64.7
Europe  Azerbaijan  29.3
Europe  Belarus 6.8
Europe  Belgium 104.6
Europe  Bosnia and Herzegovina  21.2
Europe  Bulgaria    44.3
Europe  Croatia 17.2
```

**Update**
the follwoing code also doesn’t work

```
var data;

function doSomethingWithData(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }


d3.csv("new_data.csv", doSomethingWithData);
});
```

neither does this one

```
var localData;

function doSomething() {
    console.log(localData);
}

d3.csv("new_data.csv", function(csvData) {
   localData = csvData;
   doSomething();
});
```

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 But I do not see anything in the console with console.log i should see something there

Comment: Sorry, I misread... see this. d3 methods like this are asynchronous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: It will be helpful to see `new_data.csv`

Comment: @nnattawat added data